# Composite collider 2D mysteriously adds x velocity to player rigidbody

Tags: unity, platformer, rigidbody

[image]

As you can in the gif above there is an x velocity being set in the players rigidbody upon contact with the tilemap surface (Tilemap collider using composite). It was fine when I was using standalone colliders but now this happens.

Is this a bug or am I missing something. Help is much appreciated.

Unity ver. 2019.4.8f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting offset distance of the composite collider to zero. I don't really know why it solved but it works for now.